# sed: how to print a range of line to end of file

Tags: bash, sed

I can print a range of lines from a file using this cmd:

```
sed -n 267975,1000000p < dump-gq1-sample > dump267975
```

but how to print to the end? I tried

```
sed -n 267975,$p < dump-gq1-sample > dump267975
```

and it gives me:

> sed: 1: "267975,": expected context address

Comment: Use quotes: `sed -n '267975,$p' < dump-gq1-sample > dump267975`, otherwise your shell expands `$p` to (in your case) the empty string: without quotes, your command was equivalent to `sed -n 267975,` and that's why `sed` complains.

Answer (score 24):

You're the victim of [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

```
sed -n 267975,$p < dump-gq1-sample > dump267975
```

is received by `sed` as

```
sed -n 267975, < dump-gq1-sample > dump267975
```

because the `p` variable is undefined.

You should quote your parameter with single quotes `'`

```
sed -n '267975,$p' < dump-gq1-sample > dump267975
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html For the full list of existing shell expansions.

Answer (score 7):

the single-quote response does not work in cases where the start/end of range are passed to sed as a variable.

including a space between the end-symbol $ and p in single quotes works on my systems to prevent unintended expansion of $p

```
sed -n '267975,$ p' ${INPUT_FILE} > ${OUTPUT_FILE} #double quotes work here too
```

If you need to pass the initial line as a variable, double quotes are required for the expansion of $L1 so the space is generally a good idea:

```
L1=267975
sed -n "${L1},$ p" ${INPUT_FILE} > dump${L1}
```